# DispatchQueue.main when iOS app is in background mode?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

What happend if URLSession sends request and before getting response iOS app goes into background mode, will `self.myLabel.text` get update?, will DispatchQueue.main work?

```
func updateUILabel(callback :(NSDictionary?) -> Void ){


    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "https:anyserver.xyz”)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async({
              guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
              }

              let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
              if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                 self.myLabel.text = responseJSON[“text”] as! String
              }
       })
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this,

```
func updateUILabel(callback :(NSDictionary?) -> Void ){


    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "https:anyserver.xyz”)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async({
              guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
              }

              let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
              if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                //Update
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       self.myLabel.text = responseJSON[“text”] as! String                         

                 }

              }
       })
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I just updated this,

```
//Update
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       self.myLabel.text = responseJSON[“text”] as! String                         

                 }
```

Comment: Does ' DispatchQueue.main.async' work if app quickly goes into background mode after calling URLSession?, what is behaviour of main thread if app is in background mode meantime?

Comment: Yes I have done once for my code, but as best practice we should not update any UI when app goes to  background instead what we can do that we collect those data while app is in background and when app comes to foreground we can update our UI, Also you can save you response string in NSUserDefault while app is in background and when app comes to foreground you can update you label from that userdefault here is turoria that might help you, https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this case, you must use **weak self** instead of **strong self** to avoid memory leak or safely access.
And use DispatchQueue.main.async for code update UI only :)

```
func updateUILabel(callback :(NSDictionary?) -> Void ){


    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "https:anyserver.xyz”)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {[weak self] data, response, error in
           guard let data = data, error == nil else {
              print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
              return
           }
           let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
              if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                //Update
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       self?.myLabel?.text = responseJSON[“text”] as? String                         

                 }

              }
       })
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I have added **[weak self]** before your closure and update **self?.myLabel?.text =** ...

Following apple document, you should not update any view from background mode.

"**Avoid updating your windows and views**. Because your app’s windows and views are not visible when your app is in the background, you should avoid updating them. The exception is in cases where you need to update the contents of a window prior to having a snapshot of your app taken." 
Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: ya, you are right, i didn't add [weak self]. but how can label be updated from background? plz give me any link..

Comment: @sulabhqg sorry i have updated my answer, following apple document, you  shouldn't update any view in background mode.
"Avoid updating your windows and views. Because your app’s windows and views are not visible when your app is in the background, you should avoid updating them. The exception is in cases where you need to update the contents of a window prior to having a snapshot of your app taken."
Link: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html